# Retrieve only the value from the tags in an XML file in codename one

Tags: xml, iteration, codenameone

I'm quite new to java, but i couldn't find a method that shows ONLY the "value" of a tag from an XML file.

The file I attached can explain better what I mean, hopefully...

I would like to retrieve a string with value ="1", and then a second string with value = "Logge dei banchi", etc etc

Thanks in advance, and I hope I have been clear enough.
Luca
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dUHc.png)

Comment: I solved working with string methods... It's not "clean" as I would like, but finally it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute values can be extracted with `String value = element.getAttribute("AttrName");`.

The body is a bit harder:

```
Vector v = elem.getTextDescendants(null, false, 1);
if(v != null && v.size() > 0) {
   Element actual = (Element)v.get(0);
   String text = actual.getText();
   // ....
}
```

The reason for that complexity is that it's completely legal in XML to do something like this:

```
<aaa>body<bbb/>rest of body</aaa>
```

So if you get the body of `aaa` you would have a problem. So when a parser "sees" text it converts it to a text element so what you get in the parse tree is 3 children under `aaa` a text element, `bbb` and another text element.